# AngularMaterial: Custom md-tab-label in md-tabs

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-material

According to [md-tab Documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.tabs/directive/mdTab) we can have custom `md-tab-label`, which I'm trying to do like this:

```
<md-tab-label class="my-label">
   Label
</md-tab-label>
```

My css:

```
.my-label{
    background: #40FF00;
}
```

However, the background color is not appearing for tab labels.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You want to display a label in a tab?

Comment: No..that can be done via label attribute inside the tab.
I want to display a custom label, with some background inside the tab, for which I'm using md-tab-label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I was doing this the wrong way.
The correct way is:

1. Define your markup
2. Then add css

In this case, the css can be like:

```
all-tabs {font-size: 20px;}
.demo-tab {
  color:green;
}
```

and in html:

```
<md-tab-label>
   <all-tabs class="demo-tab">  {{$index+1}} </all-tabs>
</md-tab-label>
```

Resulting tabs:
[image]

Comment: it's also way of binding html in tab label

Comment: For Anyone wondering what's the tag for the tab content when using <md-tab-label>, you can place all content within <md-tab-body> tags, otherwise it wont show up